# The location of package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

1. Is there an official specification for the location of package.json in the project? Such as under the project
2. Where will the package.json of the multi-component project be placed
3. Why is version 0.0.0 in package.json?What does this represent？

Comment: Version 0.0.0 broadly means "unreleased". It's also very likely "unversioned". When you create a project, you might have a lot of work to do that doesn't make sense to version. For example, setting up a framework, adding dependencies, etc., all tasks to do with setting up the project. Since it's not ready for usage by others, it doesn't make much sense to say "it's version 0.0.1" or whatever. You typically increase the version when you *add* to or *change* the project. Assuming it's already released in some fashion.

Comment: thanks a lot！！！！ Can you answer my question1 and question2?

Answer (score 0):

here is the official documents of npm about package.json: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#name . As it is said, if you don't want to publish the package, any name and version could be used, like what you mentioned, the "0.0.0".